# Android Lint misidentifying unused resources

Tags: android, android-lint

Android Lint thinks I have some unused resources, like 
`data0454.xml`
whereas actually the file is being used in a loop, like this:

```
"data" + numberString + ".xml"
```

What should I do about this - change my program design, or try to hide the Android Lint warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't refer to resources via `"data" + numberString + ".xml"`. Resources do not have file extensions.

That being said, assuming that are you are actually getting the resources (e.g., `getResources().getIdentifier()`), you'll probably want to suppress the Lint warning for this project.